# yup custom error messages not in ValidationError object

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

The [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) `ValidationError` object doesn't have the custom error messages.

```js
let data = {
    foo: "aaa"
}

let schema = 
    yup.object().shape({
        foo: yup.number().integer('Custom "must be a number" error message!')
    });

try {

    let validated = await schema.validate(data, { abortEarly: false })

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.errors[0]) // foo must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN`
    console.log(err.inner[0].message) // foo must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN`
}
```

I should get `Custom "must be a number" error message!` at `err.inner[0].message`.

[Here's the codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-chatelet-lpgi5?file=/src/index.js)

What am I doing wrong? [I'm doing it as shown here.](https://leomotta.me/posts/data-validation-with-yup/)

Answer (score 11):

You should use `try / catch` block to catch async/await errors, like synchronous code.

Also you can't directly pass a message to the `number()` type function, instead you have to pass `typeError`

```js
import * as yup from "yup";

const fn = async () => {
  let data = {
    foo: "a"
  };

  let schema = yup.object().shape({
    foo: yup.number().typeError("Custom not a number message!")
  });

  try {
    await schema.validate(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
};

fn();
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I updated the code. [It's the same approach as shown here.](https://leomotta.me/posts/data-validation-with-yup/)

Comment: It is working in my sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/yup-gptbk?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

with 0.32.11
this seems to work:

```
string()
      .required('Email is require')
      .email('Email is not valid')
```

Comment: and if its not an email ??? lets say name ? or address ? do we do something like `.address('the address is not right')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Today date is 2/8/2023, as per [yup documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#customizing-errors), you can customize error message via test method chained after the yup object defenitions. Here is an example:

```js
let PaymentSchema = yup.object({
    fullname: yup.string().required().test({
      name: 'fullname',
      skipAbsent: true,
      test(value, ctx) {
        if (!value.startsWith('Agent')) {
          return ctx.createError({ message: 'SKU missing correct prefix' })
        }
        if (!value.endsWith('-alpha-male')) {
          return ctx.createError({ message: 'SKU missing correct suffix' })
        }
        if (value.length < 10) {
          return ctx.createError({ message: 'SKU is not the right length' })
        }
        return true
      }
    })
  })
```